# A scss variable doesn't return the css variable value

Tags: css, sass

I have two css variables and two scss variables , the problem is the last scss variable doesn't return a value at all.
note that the values of the two sass variables comes from the css variables.
the first scss variable takes its value normally from the css variable.

```
:root {
  --intro-img-url: url("../images/pexels-los-muertos-crew-7487374.jpg");
  --dl-mode: black;
}

// the intro-img scss variable takes its value normally from the 
// css variable and there's no problem with it.

$intro-img: var(--intro-img-url);

// but the dl-mode scss variable doesn't take the css variable val
// and just return nothing

$dl-mode: var(--dl-mode);

@if $dl-mode == black {
  :root {
    --dominant1-wmode-color: #030712;
    --dominant1-bmode-color: #ffffff;
  }
} @else {
  :root {
    --dominant1-wmode-color: green;
    --dominant1-bmode-color: #030712;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though `--dl-mode` is set to `black` in the context of `:root`, the value of `$dl-mode` is set to `var(--dl-mode)`. This is what your SCSS compiler will be seeing when it runs the check `@if $dl-mode == black`, so that check will always be false.

SCSS cannot look inside the values of CSS variables, because it needs to know those values at compile time but those values may depend on context within the HTML itself. For example, consider the following:

```
:root {
    --my-var: black;
}

.class {
    --my-var: white;
}

$my-var: var(--my-var);

@if $my-var == black {
    // How can you know the value within --my-var if you don't know if you're in a .class element or not?
}
```

Comment: How the SCSS cannot look inside the values of CSS variables and the first SASS variable In my question returns the value normally and I use the it normally ?? or you mean that in the check itself the SCSS will look the the value of the variable as normal text??

Comment: @if $dl-mode == var(--dl-mode) {} // OMG the check returned true  with me when doing it like that !!!!

Comment: why SCSS consider the value of  a SCSS variable as string when only checking??

Comment: Remember, SCSS isn't interpreted by the browser. It's only used by your SCSS compiler to create CSS. Then that CSS is what gets interpreted by the browser. To put it very simply, CSS is made up of strings, so SCSS builds it by putting strings together. Sure, it understands how to do stuff like multiplying numbers together, but in the end it's just figuring out how to put all the strings together correctly.

Comment: Do you see my first SCSS variable?? this variable's value comes from the CSS variable and the value is just an image , in JS I just made a function returns random path and set it to the CSS root variable here ,  and I'm now confused like how the compiling happens in the browser and you say the browser doesn't compile !!

Comment: I used to think the the compiling happens once but I'm confused about my first SCSS variable just compiling in the browser according to the random value returns from the JS to the CSS root and I saw that the browser compiled that normally.

Comment: The browser never sees your SCSS variables. 1 - You write SCSS. 2 - Your SCSS compiler turns the SCSS you wrote into CSS. 3 - The browser reads and interprets that compiled CSS. 4 - You set the value of a CSS variable using JavaScript, and the browser interprets that as it normally would. The last step has nothing to do with SCSS, your variable served its purpose in step 2 when the SCSS compiler took the string it contained and used that to build a CSS file.

Comment: Thanks man for your interest  but it sounds like I know what you're saying but I don't find the answer of  how the browser just update the SASS variable while taking an action to update the CSS variable without accessing the SASS files , I know it's not possible but I don't know how the update happens

Comment: By the time it reaches the browser, that SCSS variable doesn't exist anymore. It's been compiled into the string your stored in it, which is (in one example) `var(--dl-mode)`. That's now something the browser can understand. The SCSS variable's value isn't getting changed, only the `--dl-mode` CSS custom property, which the browser knows how to interpret. It might help for you to open the compiled CSS file directly to take a look inside, remembering that the browser will request this file but will never see the SCSS directly.

Comment: remembering that the browser will request this file but will never see the SCSS directly. (that's what I was missing)

Comment: I appreciate your help .